# sifr text width

Tags: sifr

I was wondering whether sifr-text that is rendered in flash has the same width across all browsers / flash plugins (in case I set an absolute font size). So are the proportions of a 24px Helvetica string ‘Hello’ equal, no matter what flash plugin version or browser you have?

Thanks in advance for any answers / insights!

Thijs.

Answer (score 0):

Should be, yes, provided you're using `fitExactly` so the Flash movie gets the same width as the text inside it.